# Get .wav blob from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blob, form-data

I'm trying to get a blob from an URL (in my case leads to a `.wav` file).
The URL is located at my own website, so I only do requests to the same site.

**The purpose:**

1. A user has uploaded some `.wav` files to my website to one schema
2. The user wants to copy one or more .wav files from one to another schema
3. The user selects the audiofiles to copy without uploading the files again.

The user interface looks like this:
[image]

**The problem:**

Each audiofile is located in its own directory.

> https://mywebsite.nl/media/audiofiles/schemaGUID/recording.wav

So when copying to another schema, the file or files needs to get re-uploaded to the directory of the other schema.
The code im using to upload the selected audiofiles is this:

```
newwavfiles.forEach(function (item) {
   var name = item["name"];
   var filename = item["filename"];
   var fileblob = fetch('http://mywebsite.nl/media/audiofiles/12345677/recording.wav').then(res => res.blob());
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', fileblob, filename);
   formData.append('guid', guid);
                              
   // upload file to server
   $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?action=uploadAudiofile',
      type: 'post',
      data: formData,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (response) {
                    
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         console.log(xhr);
         var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText                                          
      }
   });
});
```

To get the blob of the file I tried this:

```
var fileblob = fetch('http://mywebsite.nl/media/audiofiles/12345677/recording.wav').then(res => res.blob());
```

But then I get this error:

> Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

Does anyone have a solution to get the `.wav` file blob from an URL?

Comment: Do you have any server-side code?  (php/MVC/etc)  Would be *much* easier to have a "copyFiles" server end-point where you pass from/to filenames/"schema" GUIDs and it does the copy server-side rather than download to the client to then re-upload.

Comment: The ajax call uploads the sended blob to the directory in PHP. That works for manual uploads. How can I get the blob of a audiofile without the user uploading it again manually?